# Big Query Dijkstra

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dijkstra

I’m trying to run a Dijkstra algorithm on bigquery using 2 tables.
The first table has the node information (ID, Latitude, Longitude)
The second table has the vertex information (Start_node_ID, End_node_ID, Distance between nodes) .
I’m not really sure how to start this project, I don’t have that much experience with bigquery, I’ve seen some people make something similar on SQL so I know it’s possible, but I’m having a hard time replicating it on BigQuery.

All help is welcome, thanks for your time.

P.S here its who the data looks like, some vertexes only goes in one direction.

```
NODE

 1. |ID|LAT|LONG|
 2. |1 |1.2| 1.3|
 3. |2 |1.2| 1.4|
 4. |3 |3.4|-2.5|
```

```
VERTEX

 1. |STR|END|DST|
 2. | 1 | 2 | 3 |
 3. | 2 | 1 | 3 |
 4. | 1 | 3 | 4 |
```

I tried the following code, but im not sure how to convert it to bigquery SQL

https://kainwen.com/2019/10/31/dijkstra-via-sql-a-glance-at-recursive-cte/

Answer (score 0):

Recursive CTEs are supported in BigQuery but there are limitations that might be key for your use case.

Let's take the final SQL code explained here: https://kainwen.com/2019/10/31/dijkstra-via-sql-a-glance-at-recursive-cte/

And translate it to BigQuery:

```
create OR REPLACE table `qwiklabs-gcp-01-6fe73054adde.data.roadmap`(a int, b int, d int);
insert into `qwiklabs-gcp-01-6fe73054adde.data.roadmap` values
(1, 2, 7),
(1, 3, 9),
(1, 6, 14),
(2, 3, 10),
(2, 4, 15),
(3, 4, 11),
(3, 6, 2),
(4, 5, 6),
(5, 6, 9);

create OR REPLACE table `qwiklabs-gcp-01-6fe73054adde.data.roadmap_sym`
AS SELECT * FROM `qwiklabs-gcp-01-6fe73054adde.data.roadmap`;

insert into `qwiklabs-gcp-01-6fe73054adde.data.roadmap_sym` select b,a,d from `qwiklabs-gcp-01-6fe73054adde.data.roadmap`;
insert into `qwiklabs-gcp-01-6fe73054adde.data.roadmap_sym` values (null, null, null);
 
create OR REPLACE table `qwiklabs-gcp-01-6fe73054adde.data.known`
AS SELECT * FROM `qwiklabs-gcp-01-6fe73054adde.data.roadmap`
WHERE 1<>1;


insert into `qwiklabs-gcp-01-6fe73054adde.data.known` values (6, 3, 2);
 
with recursive sp as
(
select * from `qwiklabs-gcp-01-6fe73054adde.data.known`
union all
select a, b, d
from
(
  select
    a, b, d, s, rank() over (order by (d+s)) as rk
  from
  (
    select a, b, d, s
    from
    (
      select
      a, b, min(d) as d, sum(t) as s
      from
      (
        select
          sp.a as a,
          case
        when rm.a is null then sp.b
        else rm.b
      end as b,
          case
        when rm.a is null then sp.d
            when sp.a = rm.a then rm.d
            else sp.d + rm.d
          end as d,
      case
        when rm.a is null then 1000
        else 0
      end as t
        from
          sp, `qwiklabs-gcp-01-6fe73054adde.data.roadmap_sym` as rm
        where
      rm.a is null
      or
      (
            (sp.a = rm.a or
             sp.b = rm.a) and
            sp.a <> rm.b
      )
      ) x
      group by a, b
    )y
  )z
)q where rk = 1 or s = 1000
)
select * from sp where b = 4 limit 1;
```

BigQuery will fail while executing the CTE because of this error:

```
A subquery containing a recursive reference may not use DISTINCT, GROUP BY, or any aggregate function
```

Given that, yes you can take advantage of recursive CTEs but the existing limitations can be a blocker issue for certain queries.

Please, take a look at all the specs and limitations documented here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#recursive_keyword

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice, I tried to execute this code and I end up with the same error. Is there a way to fix it or is it impossible to do a Dijkstra in big query?

Answer (score 0):

Such functions are rather tricky to do in SQL. It usually makes sense to write JavaScript UDFs instead.

Carto wrote such routing algorithm code, you might see if you can adapt it for your data:
https://carto.com/blog/how-to-do-route-optimization-at-scale-with-carto-bigquery/